# Cannot access sitemap in yii2 project placed in root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, sitemap.xml

I have created a sitemap.xml for my yii2 project. I put it in root folder but I can't seem to access it with this URL: https://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml. I need the URL to input it to Google Search Console.

I've searched everywhere but it seems that information about yii2 and sitemap are very rare.

What is the correct way to place the sitemap.xml? I believe it can be fixed in htaccess file but I don't know how.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/font/(.*)$ backend/web/font/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/plugins/(.*)$ backend/web/plugins/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/images/(.*)$ backend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/img/(.*)$ backend/web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/app-assets/(.*)$ backend/web/app-assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|font|plugins|images|img|js|app-assets)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|font|uploads)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ frontend/web/img/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ frontend/web/uploads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|img|images|font|fonts|uploads|plugins|app-assets)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

 # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

It's been weeks trying to solve this with no success. Please help.

Comment: "I can't seem to access it" - What happens? What response are you getting exactly? (A 404 from your framework perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. But the solution is actually very simple, I've just found out.

I moved my sitemap.xml file to frontend/web folder and it works.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
> ```

You need to remove the `OR` flag on the above condition, otherwise this expression (*not a file OR not a directory*) will *always* be true and requests for `sitemap.xml` (or any other static resource not already excluded in the preceding *condition*) will be routed to `frontend/web/index.php`.

These two *negated* conditions should be implicitly AND'd, not `OR`'d.

Answer (score 0):

I could be nice to use some "dynamic in there":
You can make a new controller like `frontend\controllers\SitemapController` and serve it in 'FORMAT_RAW'.

Additionaly - 'sitemap.xml' => 'sitemap/index', in urlManager. (controller/view)